# How to include directories and subdirectories in a batch file

Tags: command-line, bash, metadata, batch, mkv

I found a batch file script to do the job I need to do. I posed the question of how to add directories and subdirectories recursively in the batch process in a comment on the post I got this code from, but no one replied after 4 months. I couldn't find an answer to this question searching this site so I figured id start a new thread on the topic.

What I wanted to do was be able to bulk change meta data information in MKV files which was accomplished thusly.

```
#!/bin/bash

# This script takes all mkv files in the current directory and sets the filename
# (without .mkv) as its title in metadata

for mkvfile in *.mkv; do
mkvpropedit "$mkvfile" -e info -s title="${mkvfile::-4}"
done
```

How can I modify this to be run on a root directory to include all folders and sub-folders in the process?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

With bash, you'd set the `globstar` and `nullglob` shell options and use `**` to recurse into subdirectories:

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob
for mkvfile in **/*.mkv; do
    mkvpropedit "$mkvfile" -e info -s title="${mkvfile::-4}"
done
```

See [4.3.2 The Shopt Builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Shopt-Builtin)
in the manual.

Note you can also use `${mkvfile%.mkv}` to chop off the extension.

You can also use find, but I think it gets pretty ugly

```
find . -name '*.mkv' -exec sh -c 'mkvpropedit "$1" -e info -s title="$(basename "${1%.mkv}")"' sh {} \;
```

Comment: Getting error
shopt: not found, Bad substitution

Comment: Are you using `/bin/bash` or `/bin/sh` ? shopt is bash-specific.

Comment: /bin/bash - same as the code sample I provided.

Comment: find . -name '*.mkv' -exec sh -c 'mkvpropedit "$1" -e info -s title="${1%.mkv}"' sh {} \; Works like a charm but it puts the directory path in the metadata name also.

Comment: Silly me I had a typo in the new script. Apologies, your script works perfectly. No error after the correction. ;)

Comment: Any suggestion to preventing the directory tree being included in the meta data information?

Comment: Answer updated to remove the directory from the title string.

Comment: getting closer, what that change did was took the ./ from the beginning of the file name but left the rest of the directory name in the title string. So from " ./instruction/class1/innovation.mkv " to " instruction/class1/innovation.mkv "

Comment: Really? What does this output for you: `sh -c 'echo title="$(basename "${1%.mkv}")"' - "./foo/bar/baz.mkv"` ? And if the result is not `title=baz`, then what is your OS (and version) and what is /bin/sh on your system?

Comment: Nothing just goes to >

Comment: Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Release: 16.04
Codename: xenial
GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: echo $SHELL
/bin/bash

Comment: Trying to change shells to /bin/sh no command is letting it change its stuck in bash. I cant seem to get the version of /bin/sh but cat is telling me its installed.

Comment: `ls -l /bin/sh` would be informative.

Comment: The output of that command is - lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Feb 17  2016 /bin/sh -> dash

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77355/discussion-between-themegolith-and-glenn-jackman).